# Bootstrap Label Surrounding Checkbox and Input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a form that has a checkbox that is inline with a text input. Here's what I did to make it look nice with bootstrap:

```
<label class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="keywords" value="__option__">
  <input type="text" name="keywords_other_option" value="" placeholder="Other">
</label>
```

It looks good, but it doesn't function well. In firefox, the user can't type in the textbox. Is there a good bootstrap way to put the checkbox and the text input inline with each other?

Comment: I'd recommended looking at the docs for `form-inline`: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms. The example they provide includes just that :).

Comment: Don't put two inputs inside one label.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Don't put two `input` elements inside one `label` element.

And here is Twitter Bootstrap way to solve this:

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <label class="checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" name="keywords" value="__option__">
  </label>
  <input type="text" name="keywords_other_option" value="" placeholder="Other">
</form>
```

Here is **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8tw7v/)**.

Look more examples from [official documentation](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms).

Comment: That's the one. I changed the form to a div since this was already inside of a form though.